# Reverse engineering port on laser for rotary attachment

Tags: reverse-engineering, laser, port

I have a Trotec Speedy 300. It has the ability to control a rotary attachment by plugging it into a 12 pin Molex port inside the printer. The attachment costs over $1500 plus shipping from the company so I want to see if I can make my own.

I have a good photo from inside the cambet so I can get a good look how its wired. All the wires go into one black sleeve then split off into two different gray cables. How do I go about finding how how it communicates with the rotary attachment?

[image: motion control port from inside side cabinet]

From the few photos I have seen that show inside the Trotec rotary attachment it seems like it has some kind of circuit board so maybe it does the stepper motor control on board I don't know.

[image: Trotec rotary attachment]

What would be be the best way to find out what communication system it uses and how best to make my own rotary attachment that communicates with the laser so I can engrave round objects?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I found a video that shows inside the attachment and shows that they are not using a stepper motor but instead two wire a DC motor with 4 wire encoder on the back. This leads me to believe the onboard circuit is just a DC motor driver. I need to test for voltages but I am guessing it's 12 or 24V.

I think the main board just sends power and a PWM signal to the attachment and uses the encoder for accuracy. If this is true then it would not be hard to replicate.

[image: motor for attachment]

Comment: Unless someone else has reverse engineered this unit the way forward it is reverse engineer it yourself. Short of buying the item, see if you can get as many high resolution pictures as you can.

Comment: So I have found a few more photos of the company made attachment and oddly enough it does not seem to use a stepper motor but a normal DC motor with a encoder on it. I need to spend some time testing pins on the connector and seeing what I find when I run a test job. I'm guessing it uses the encoder to known how much the dc moror has moved and has some kind of motor driver on board.

Comment: How do you know what type of motor it is? Steppers can have encoders as well

Comment: See the update, in the photo you can see the motor only had a red and black wire, steppers always have four or more wires, two per coil. This is clearly a DC motor with 4 wire encoder on it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Crank out your DMM and oscilloscope!